# struggling in visualizing the set relation to calculate probability

Tags: probability, elementary-probability

Given this problem, "Suppose that 55% of all adults regularly consume coffee, 45% regularly consume carbonated soda, and 70% regularly consume at least one of the two. "  I have two questions to solve. The first, "What is the probability that a randomly selected adult regularly consumes both?"  So,   let $A$ be adults consuming coffee and $B $ be those consuming carbonated soda. I know that I'm being asked to calculate $A \cap B$ but I'm not quite seeing how to visualize it into the pattern given in the book, $P(A \cup B)=P (A) +P (B)-P (A \cap B) $.  I've got the following which I hope means I'm on the right track $A= A\cap B + A \cap B'$ and $B=A\cap B+A'\cap B $.  Am I, or should I be looking somewhere else for alternate ways of representation to calculate the probability of $A\cap B $?

Thanks

Comment: Just to say:  language matters for problems like this and for the coffee drinkers you leave off the "regularly".  I imagine we are to assume that it is there anyway, but it changes the answer if you imagine that there are some people who drink coffee, but not regularly.

Comment: In general, there are four types of people:  type $A$ drinks only coffee, type $B$ drinks only soda, type $C$ drinks both, type $D$ drinks neither.  Write down what you know in terms of those four types.

Comment: @lulu yes, sorry, the word "regularly" is included

Comment: Sure, I figured.  Take a look at the hint I wrote.  It should solve your problem.

Comment: @lulu one of the questions I've had is how to correctly interpret, "... at least one of these two..."  Should that be, "at least one but not necessarily both," or, "at least one and usually both?"

Comment: So, using my letters (and letting each stand for the percent membership in that type) we have $A+B+C+D=1$, of course.  The first condition says that $A+C=.55$ as $A\cup C$ comprises all those who drink coffee (and my types are mutually exclusive, that's why I chose them).  The second condition says $B+C=.45$ and the third says that $A+B+C=.7$ Does that make sense?

Comment: In words, if you tell me "I drink soda", I can't immediately tell which type you are.  You might be $B$ or $C$, according to whether you drink coffee or not.  Thus all I know is that you belong to $B \cup C$.

Comment: @lulu yes that does and I haven't thought of it as $A+C=.55$. I was thinking simply in terms of $A=.55$.  Thank you.

Comment: As a general rule:  I always try to describe things in mutually exclusive categories.  That makes the algebra a lot easier.  The difficulty is often, as here, that you then have to translate all the given information over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following Venn Diagram:

[image]

Note that:

$A = I \cup II$

$B = II \cup III$

$A \cap B = II$

$A \cup B = I \cup II \cup III$

Now, if you count everything that is inside the $A$ circle ($I$ + $II$), and you add to this everything that is inside the $B$ circle ($II$ + $III$), then you have counted everything that is inside $A \cap B$ ($II$) twice, so to count everything that is inside the union of $A$ and $B$ ($I + II + III$), you need to subtract everything that is inside $A \cap B$ ($II$) once. Hence:

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$

From this, it follows that:

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B) = 0.55 + 0.45 - 0.7 = 0.3$$

Comment: this is precisely the relationship I have in my question. I'm understanding the question to be "... only those who have both regularly. "  That is, the region of the intersection of $A $ and $B $.

Comment: OK, so you know $70$% of people are in the union. GIven that $55$% are inside $A$, that leaves $70-55=15$ in the region inside $B$ but outside $A$. Likewise, since $45$% is inside $B$, that leaves $70-45=25$ inside $A$ but outside $B$. And that means that $70-15-25=30$ is in the intersection of $A$ and $B$

Comment: Marking this as the answer.  After a question to the professor as well, I realized my mistake.  I was incorrectly thinking of the adults who regularly, "... consume at least one of the two...," as being a different _circle_ or a _third circle_ in a Venn Diagram.  This was incorrect, as was pointed out here as well, since this group is  $A \cup B$.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:**

Looking at a Venn Diagram is often helpful, and you may learn something 
about this particular problem by
assigning a probability to each of the regions of a properly drawn
Venn Diagram [which would also have a region for $(A\cap B)^\prime$, 
'regularly consumes neither type of beverage'].

I believe this problem was supposed to reinforce the 'general addition rule'
$P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B),$ as follows:

$.70 = P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B) = .55 + .45 - P(A\cap B)
= 1 - P(A\cap B),$

which implies $P(A\cap B) = .30.$

*Note:* Also, $P[(A \cup B)^\prime] = P(A^\prime \cap B^\prime) = .30.$